# Is it possible to use a switch with three conditionals and the color sensor to compare?

Tags: ev3, sensor-colour

I am using an EV3 robot.

Is there a way to program it using a switch, or another way, to compare multiple colors?

The goal is to have the robot act as a car and use the color sensor to recognize red to stop, yellow to slow down and green to go in any given order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a switch statement is present in EV3-G.
Such statement would look like this:
[image]

However, the only colors you can switch against are black, blue, green, yellow, red, white and brown (the basic lego colors). So unfortunately no orange.